# How to how that $\mathsf{Ker}(f)=n\mathbb Z$ where $n$ is the characteristic of $R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $(R, +, \cdot)$ be a ring with identity $1_R$ and consider the ring of integers $(\mathbb Z, +, \cdot)$ with the usual operations.

Define the map $f:\mathbb Z\longrightarrow R$ as:

$$f(m):=\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
\underbrace{1_R+\ldots+1_R}_m & \textrm{if}& m>0\\
0 & \textrm{if} & m=0\\
\underbrace{-1_R-\ldots-1_R}_{-m} & \textrm{if} &m<0 
\end{array}\right..$$
How can I show that $\mathsf{Ker}(f)=n\mathbb Z$ where $n$ is the characteristic of $R$?

The inclusion $n\mathbb Z\subset \mathsf{Ker}(f)$ is immediate but how about the reverse inclusion?

Thanks

**Remark**. The **characteristic** of a ring is the least positive integer $n$ such that:

$$\underbrace{1_R+\ldots+1_R}_n=0.$$ If there is not such integer, we say the ring has **zero characteristic**.

Comment: What is your definition of characteristic of a ring?

Comment: The usual definition of the characteristic of a unital ring is the positive generator of the kernel of the unique unital ring homomorphism $\Bbb{Z}\ \longrightarrow\ R$. So I wonder what definition you are using.

Comment: I added the definition =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $m\in\mathbb Z$ and suppose that $m\in\ker f$. Write $m$ as $qn+r$, with $r\in\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$. Then$$0=f(m)=f(qn+r)=f(r),$$since $f(n)=0$. But you can't have $f(r)=0$ unless $r=0$, since otherwise $r\in\{1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$. So, $r=0$, and it follows then from $m=bq+r$ that $m\in n\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Thanks a lot =)

Comment: I'm glad I could help.